# How To Create an Empty TableRow in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I have the following layout for my andriod app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ULC Background"
android:stretchColumns="1">
    <!--Below I try to create an 'empty' table to push down the buttons 200 pixels, but it doesn't work, it doesn't affect the layout at all-->
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200dip"></TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="@string/startButtonText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="@string/exitButtonText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The buttons look really weird right at the top, I want them pushed down 200 pixels, how can I do that?

I tried creating an 'empty' TableRow, but that didn't  work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table rows have [paddingTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingTop) like most views, just use that